# Data Icon not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to turn Data Icons into navigation. The icons are clickable in Firefox and Chrome, but they are not clickable in Safari. Thanks for your help! Here's my mark-up:

```
<a href="#"><span data-icon="!" aria-hidden="true" class="close"></span></a>
```

Comment: In what context is this? Are you using some sort of framework? [data-](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) attributes are just attributes that you can use to define custom data. See: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: can you show your css.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was CSS related. I needed to add a width and height to the li and then display:block and height/width: 100% in the span.